# Why does writing raw byte to a partition not working [sector writing]?

Tags: c, sector

I have a usb key I want to write on directly to its first sector but it doesn't work at all. I tried to write a cross-platform (BSD/Linux/Windows) code for that (code below) but it doesn't do anything:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc < 4)
    {
        printf("Usage : %s src_path dst_path bytecount", argv[0]);
    }   

    FILE * src;
    FILE * dst;
    char buffer[512];

    int readcount;
    int writecount;

    src = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(src == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file %s for reading : %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dst = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if(dst == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file %s for writing : %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    readcount  = fread(buffer,  1, atoi(argv[3]), src);
    writecount = fwrite(buffer, 1, atoi(argv[3]), dst);

    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

since it wasn't working I thought at least I would try a platform specific code using posix function like so:

```
//same previous headers plus some extra
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //same condition here   

    int src;
    int dst;
    char buffer[512];

    int readcount;
    int writecount;

    src = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(src == -1)
    {
        //same error message
    }

    dst = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY);
    if(dst == -1)
    {
        //same error message
    }

    readcount  = read(src,  buffer, atoi(argv[3]));
    writecount = write(dst, buffer, atoi(argv[3]));

    close(src);
    close(dst);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

it too didn't work either. I have to mention that I try both code on FreeBSD as sudo and the first code on windows as administrator Since I know, from another code I found, that I needed permission to run this thing.

As mentioned above I found another code that does almost what I want but it's in WIN API C++ (C++ using some Windows specific instructions). Unfortunately not only it's not cross platform but I don't know enough about WIN API C++ to make a cross platform C version of it or to change it so that instead of fill a whole sector or more it copies enough from the source file that I want to copy to the destination sector(s).

**[EDIT]**

When I run my program on FreeBSD I use the command `sudo ./copier source.bin /dev/da0s1` 436 it runs without telling me any error happened and for windows I use the command `copier.exe e:\source.bin \\.\N:` (N: being the partition N) in a administrator cmd and I get "Permission denied"

Also I just added to more instructions to know how many bytes were read and written:

```
printf("read %d byte(s)\n", readcount);
printf("wrote %d byte(s)\n", writecount);
```

I get a 436 bytes read with the above command and -1 bytes written. at least on the posix code. The cross-platform code tells me 436 bytes were written but when I check the hexadecimal raw data for the partition ; nothing has changed.

As suggested by Erdal Küçük I added the following instruction to get the error message after the write:

in Posix code :

```
if(writecount == -1)
{
    printf("Couldn't write to file %s : %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
}
```

in ANSI C code :

```
if(writecount != atoi(argv[3]))
{
    printf("Couldn't write to file %s : %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
}
```

When I run the POSIX code on FreeBSD I get an error message

> Couldn't write to file /dev/da0s1 : Invalid argument

When I run the cross platform code on FreeBSD ; the error message doesn't appear at all. On windows the cross platform code gives me a strange error message :

> Couldn't write to file \\.\N: : No error

basically it couldn't write but `errno` is not an error ?

Windows tells me 0 byte(s) where written.

Comment: What does it mean exactly that it doesn't work "at all"? You should probably check the return value of `read()` and `write()` too. Even though permissions issues on Unixen are checked on `open()`, they might also tell you something.

Comment: How do you determine that is doesn't work? If you suspect that some read/write fails, then maybe some error checking would be in order?

Comment: @ilkkachu and @HAL9000 I use the command `sudo od -t x1 -A n path_to_file > output_file` to check the output of both the source and the destination and they do not match. I will add a test for `read()` and `write()` to know how many was read and written

Comment: @ilkkachu and @HAL9000 I've added a few printf to show me the values of `readcount` and `writecount`.  It prints "read 436 byte(s)" and "wrote -1 byte(s)". clearly the writing is the issue. Also if I don't use sudo I get the predictible "Permission denied"

Comment: Now, do a `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno))` right after `write` and tell us the result.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno))`  after `write()` gives me "invalide argument"

Comment: `EINVAL - fd  is attached to an object which is unsuitable for writing`. Is `/dev/da0s1` a device or a partition?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük it is a partition. the device is, I think, `/dev/da`. Also like I told HAL9000 and ilkkachu above I checked the binary code (raw data) of `/dev/da0s1` and it does match with what I get when I check the partition's raw value on Windows (using HxD). is `EINVAL` similar to the message I get from errno (Permission denied) because I don't see any `EINVAL`

Comment: `errno` is `EINVAL` which is translated by `strerror` to "Invalid Argument."

Comment: `open` != `read` != `write`. Try to write at `/dev/da`. The partition table might get messed up by this, but if you want to write to the first sector, you do it anyways. Do a `ls` first and look what the device is.

Comment: @PaikuHan, if the behaviour is different between FreeBSD and Windows, you may need to focus on them one at a time. I wouldn't be at all surprised if there's a difference in writing to raw disks between them.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük about `/dev/da` when I remove the flash drive `/dev/da` disappear (just like `/dev/da0s1`) . Now when I do `ls /dev/da` I get "/dev/da" when I try to mount it to check its content using `mount_msdosfs /dev/da /mnt/destpath` I get "Invalid argument". If I try to modify its raw bytes with my posix code I also get `errno` == "Invalid argument" and `writecount == -1` If I try to modify the raw bytes with the cross platform code I get no error and 436 bytes written. but when I check the raw bytes, they don't match. Also note that the raw bytes of `/dev/da` don't match with `/dev/da0s1`

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should check the mount flags of the device by running sudo mount.

Ensure that the subject device is mounted as r/w and not ro.  If that doesn’t help, I have a suspicion that you could remedy this with a call to sync()

Another relevant design choice would be to make buffer dynamically allocated with a call to malloc(), rather than a fixed size which can cause buffer overrun and undefined behavior. Be sure to free that memory with the corresponding call to free()

Comment: The question is about writing to the raw device, not accessing its filesystem. No mount is necessary.

Comment: From what I've seen I shouldn't mount the device (if I do the resulting mount point is a folder) : BSD treats its devices as files so I should be able to override part of that file somehow. In fact I even checked with a hex view (command od) if the content of the file (not the mount point) was the same as a FAT32 partition and it was in fact.

Comment: One other comment - It is typically a good idea on this site to offer suggestions such as this (i.e. that are not hard clear answers that address the question directly.) with comments under the original post.   This way, if your comment is helpful everybody wins, if not, nobody looses.